# Contact Form 7 and "Load More" Duplicate Fields?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

Is it possible to have a "load more" button on a Contact Form 7 form that would just duplicate another field set on the form? I need to create a form that will allow restaurant owners to enter each item on their menu, and was wanting to display something like the following:

Item title (text field)
Menu section (dropdown -- appetizer/entree/side/dessert)

These fields would then be followed by a "load more" button that, when clicked, would generate another Item title/menu section field set. The button would need to be indefinitely clickable to generate as many field sets as needed for the user to enter all of their menu items.

I've seen the CF7 Conditional Logic plugin, but it seems like I'd have to specify how many additional "hidden" field sets I'd want, and the number of them available to the user would be finite depending on how many I added to the back end form. I need the field sets duplicated/generated on the fly.

Any help is appreciated, and please go easy if I'm not posting correctly or in the right area. This is my first time posting here :)

Comment: You need to post more details about what you have done until now, the expected behavior and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I haven't done anything, because I'm not sure what the first step to creating something like this might be. 

I'm not sure how much more detail I can give about the behavior I'm trying to achieve?